# How to handle sliding doors and inactive buttons

Tags: html, css

I have a solution like this : http://jsfiddle.net/snowman/sns2J/

As you can see in the example I have to include the following :

```
.paging .inactive a:hover
{
    background-position:    100% -26px;
    border-width:            0px;
    cursor:                 default;
}
.paging .inactive a:hover span
{
    background-position:    0 -26px;
    color:                    #d9d9d9;
    cursor:                 default;
}
```

To inactivet the hover effect.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Use [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) to distinguish between anchors `<a>` which have `href` attributes and those which don't:

```
.paging a
{
    background: transparent url('http://imgur.com/bExgs.png') no-repeat scroll top right;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font: normal 12px arial, sans-serif;
    height: 26px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding-right: 13px; /* sliding doors padding */
    text-decoration: none;
}
.paging a span
{
    background: transparent url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4JSY.png') no-repeat;
    display: block;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 13px;
}
/* Commented Backslash Hack hides rule from IE5-Mac \*/
.paging a span {float:none;}
/* End IE5-Mac hack */
.paging a[href]:hover span{
    color:            black;
}
.paging .current a
{
    background-position:    100% -52px;
    border-width:            0px;
}
.paging .current a span
{
    background-position:    0 -52px;
    color:                    black;
}
.paging .inactive a
{
    background-position:    100% -26px;
    border-width:            0px;
}
.paging
{
    list-style:     none;
    margin:         0px;
    padding:        0px;
    color:          #444444;
    font:           12px arial,sans-serif;
}

.paging li
{
    margin-left:    0px;
    float:          left;
}

.paging .inactive a span
{
    background-position:    0 -26px;
    color:                    #d9d9d9;
}

.paging .inactive a[href]:hover
{
    background-position:    100% -26px;
    border-width:            0px;
    cursor:                 default;
}
/*
.paging .inactive a:hover span
{
    background-position:    0 -26px;
    color:                    #d9d9d9;
    cursor:                 default;
}
*/
.paging a[href]:hover
{
    background-position:        100% -52px;
    color:                    black;
}
.paging a[href]:hover span{
      background-position:        0 -52px;
}
```

Comment: > Why is this better then the already existing version? Also when hover the inactive button text wrong mouse pointer will be used?

Comment: @SnowJim - Not necessarily better, but different. Change the `cursor` property to fix the mouse pointer problem.